# WordPress Displaying Thumbnails Vertically

Tags: css, javascript, thumbnails, woocommerce-offtopic

WordPress is displaying my thumbnails vertically and VERY LARGE. Specifically it's displaying WooCommerce product page thumbnails vertically and VERY LARGE. Can't seem to figure out why or what piece of code is responsible for this happening.

I already went into WordPress settings > Media, and made sure thumbnail sizes were correct at 150x150. Also tried disabling every plugin minus WooCommerce and that also didn't do the job.

This is on a cloned version of the main site that I deployed for testing/development purposes. The address is `http://192.34.63.150` (That is the address directly to the site. The issue presents itself when you go to a page such as `http://192.34.63.150/shop/directioner/)`

Here in an image of the issue: [image]

Comment: Show us the code that you're using rather than letting us try and guess. Is this a fully Woocommerce generated page?
It could be the Woocommerce settings in Settings > Product Image Sizes

Comment: @TomC I already tried messing with those settings also to no result. I forgot to include the address, I apologize. This is on a cloned version of the main site that I deployed for testing/development purposes. The address is http://192.34.63.150 (That is the address directly to the site. The issue presents itself when you go to a page such as http://192.34.63.150/shop/directioner/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended fixing this myself! After a lot of googling, I was lead to look in my wordpress uploads folder to see if Thumbnails were even being generated at all. Turns out they were not being generated! So why? For some reason my php_gd file was disabled in my php.ini file. I uncommented it, ran a regenerate thumbnails plugin in wordpress and viola! It all works now as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and answer this for you based on the limited information you've provided...

When using woocommerce, you also need to define the various image sizes for your products in the dashboard at Woocommerce > Settings > Product Image Sizes

Whatever size you choose should match the sizes in your Media Library settings, but you've already said that these are set to 150x150 so I'm guessing you've already done that 2nd part.

If you have recently changed this size, you need to run a batch to resize all the old images as the settings will only automatically apply to new products/images. Alternatively you can use the [Regen Thumbnails plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

HTH

Comment: I'm sorry, I complete forgot to include the address. This is on a cloned version of the main site that I deployed for testing/development purposes. The address is http://192.34.63.150 (That is the address directly to the site. The issue presents itself when you go to a page such as http://192.34.63.150/shop/directioner/)

Also, I have tried running the regen thumbnail plugin. I've tried a few of them, actually. What's weird is that if I navigate to an image and try to add the dimensions to the URL, I get a 404 error. Which I am assuming means the image isn't being created for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried using FTP to see if the files are actually there?